# How to completely remove eclipse after installing using installer?

Tags: uninstall, eclipse, software-uninstall

I installed eclipse using the installer from [here](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/oomph/epp/oxygen/R/eclipse-inst-linux64.tar.gz). Then, I tried to remove everything using `apt`:

```
$ sudo apt autoremove eclipse*
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package 'eclipse' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I think it will not be completely removed if I just delete the eclipse folder from my `/home` directory. Is there any clean and easy way to remove it?

Comment: What installer did you use? *.tar.gz files are not like *.deb. Unlike *.deb files *.tar.gz files have to be compiled first and then only they can be installed. Please see this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file

Comment: @ManishKumarBisht The installer is inside the *.tar.gz file. It does not have any extension. If you click on the installer inside, an interface will appear for you to install the packages you want.

Comment: As indicated by package manager, eclipse is not installed. Did the installation complete successfully? Have you used eclipse after the installation?

Comment: Search for it with `dpkg -l eclipse`, if there remove with `dpkg -P <nameofpackage>` else check inside that install folder for an **uninstall** script also without an extension.

Comment: @ManishKumarBisht Yep the installation is successful and I could launch it just fine.

Comment: @George No packages found using `dpkg -l eclipse`. I couldn't find the uninstall script as well inside the folder. :(

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you did not use apt-get or any specific package manager to install eclipse so your package managers know nothing about how to remove it.

So from my experience if you have installed it using the installer GUI WITHOUT running it as root, it will mainly create 2 directories in your home directory ~/eclipse and ~/.p2

Just delete these directories and you get back the space used by eclipse.